# Existe algum framework para auxiliar no processo de autenticação quando se usa o Google Appengine?

Tags: java, framework, spring-security, google-app-engine, single-page-application

Não quero utilizar sessão na aplicação. Spring Security seria a unica opção? Neste caso seria uma aplicação SPA.

Comment: Veja sobre o Firebase da Google. É um BaaS muito interessante: [Authenticating Users on App Engine Using Firebase](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine) [Integrar com o Google Cloud Platform](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration?hl=pt-br)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não aconselho usar `Spring Security`,em si ele é muito bom. É amplamente utilizado e todos os problemas são resolvidos com alta prioridade. No entanto, como acontece com a maioria das tecnologias, se você usá-lo indevidamente, a sua aplicação não será segura.

Sim é possível sim usar outros processos de autenticação quando se fala em autenticação através do `Google App Engine`.

**Diversas maneiras**

Segundo a própria documentação do Google,há diversos meios,alguns deles são :

**Google Identity Toolkit**

Fornece várias opções de autenticação do usuário, incluindo Google, Facebook, Yahoo, Microsoft, Paypal, e AOL. Ele também suporta o maior número de usuários, mantendo a menor quantidade de código.

**Google Sign-In**

Login do Google que oferece Gmail e Google Apps para entrar juntamente com suporte para senhas de uso único (OTP).É o método mais fácil de suportar Google-somente contas,ou apoiar contas do Google em um sistema de login existente.

**OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect**

OpenID Connect permite manipular e usar tokens de autenticação com mais personalização.

**Users API**

Usa o serviço de usuários internos API App Engine para autenticar contas do Google e do Google Apps.

**Exemplos de códigos**

Um código da documentação do Google,que exemplifica segurança e autenticação através do `Google App Engine` :

```
 <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>profile</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/profile/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>admin</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

> OBS: Os administradores de domínio do Google Apps e administradores de domínio do Google App Engine não estão incluídos no papel de administrador neste contexto. Somente os desenvolvedores de aplicativos, tais como aqueles no Visualizador de papéis / proprietário / desenvolvedor, pode acessar essas partes do aplicativo.
>
> Restrições de segurança aplicam-se a arquivos estáticos, bem como servlets.

Para saber mais,dê uma olhada na documentação deles [aqui](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/#users_api).

**Users API :**

Adicionando um novo contexto :

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)
```

Obtendo o usuário atual :

```
if u := user.Current(c); u != nil {
        g.Author = u.String()
}

key := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "Greeting", guestbookKey(c))
_, err := datastore.Put(c, key, &g)
if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
}
http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusFound)
```

> Observe que, se o usuário não está conectado, um código de status HTTP de 302 redireciona o navegador para a conta do Google tela de login.

**OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect :**

```
 // Create a state token to prevent request forgery.
  // Store it in the session for later validation.
  $state = sha1(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1024));
  $app['session']->set('state', $state);
  // Set the client ID, token state, and application name in the HTML while
  // serving it.
  return $app['twig']->render('index.html', array(
      'CLIENT_ID' => CLIENT_ID,
      'STATE' => $state,
      'APPLICATION_NAME' => APPLICATION_NAME
  ));
```

No código acima estou criando uma sessão de token única.E o código abaixo manda um pedido de requisição para o Google.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
 client_id=424911365001.apps.googleusercontent.com&
 response_type=code&
 scope=openid%20email&
 redirect_uri=https://oauth2-login-demo.example.com/code&
 state=security_token%3D138r5719ru3e1%26url%3Dhttps://oauth2-login-demo.example.com/myHome&
 login_hint=jsmith@example.com&
 openid.realm=example.com&
 hd=example.com
```

Um pedido de `request` acaba parecendo assim em seu código final :

```
POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret={client_secret}&
redirect_uri=https://oauth2-login-demo.example.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

**Pesquise e se informe mais sobre estas tecnologias**

Ambas tecnologias que foram citadas acima trabalham para fazer autenticação através do `Google App Engine`.O que posso lhe sugerir é que pesquise mais sobre tais `frameworks` para entender melhor sobre o que cada um pode lhe oferecer.Por isto vou deixar alguns artigos oficias do próprio Google para você dar mais uma olhada sobre cada um.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/authenticating-users

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/users/src/main/java/com/example/appengine/users/UsersServlet.java